# Does assigning a vector variable to itself result in copy C++

Tags: c++, copy, stdvector

Suppose I have a vector:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> foo;
foo.push_back(1);
foo.push_back(27);
```

I pass this vector to a function by reference.

```
calculate_something(foo);

int calculate_something(std::vector<uint64_t>& vec) {
  // ...
}
```

In rare circumstances, the function needs to locally modify the vector, in which case a copy must be made. Is this the correct way to do that?

```
if (some_condition) {
  vec = vec;
}

vec.push_back(7);
```

Edit: The reason I am self-assigning is because assigning to another variable results in a copy and my intuition tells me that the same would occur when assigning back to the same variable.

Comment: Most people tend to check for self-assignment, and not do anything when that happens. If it's done in your implementation of `std::vector` you have to check yourself (the source is available in the `vector` header). And even is self-assignment wasn't checked for, `vec = vec` will not create a new and unique copy that you can modify without modifying the original vector. If you really want to make a copy, you need to make an actual copy by creating a new vector and copy to it.

Comment: Can you expand you example a little bit?  `vec = vec;` is self assignment and will be ignored.

Comment: Where exactly is the copy?

Comment: @NathanOliver Question edited.

Comment: You could use a separate routine that is pass-by-value that does the rare circumstance behavior.

Comment: @Eljay And call that routine within the main routine. That is a nice idea.

Comment: References are, more or less, *aliases* of something else. The variable `vec` inside the function is an alias for the variable `foo`. Doing `vec = vec` is exactly equal to doing `foo = foo`. And that `foo = foo` assignment doesn't make any sense, do you think? It's like `int a = 5; a = a;` and expect there to be two different variables `a` in the same scope.

Comment: Regardless of whether `vec = vec;` copies `vec` to itself or not, it has the same observable effect; nothing has changed and `vec` is still the same vector as `foo`.

Comment: I don't understand this: _"In rare circumstances, the function needs to locally modify the vector, in which case a copy must be made."_ - What does `vec = vec;` solve in this case?

Comment: there is never a good reason to write `vec = vec;`. There can be good reasons to write `vec1 = vec2;` where `vec1` and `vec2` may refer to the same vector, but your code fails to illustrate that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

Assignment in C++ doesn't create new objects or change what object a reference refers to. Assignment only changes the value of the object to which the left-hand side refers (either through a built-in assignment operator or through the conventional behavior of `operator=` overloads).

In order to create new objects that persist longer than the evaluation of an expression, you need a declaration of some variable. Such a declaration can have an initializer using `=` which is often confused for assignment, which it is not:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> vec2 = vec;
```

This creates a new object `vec2` of type `std::vector<uint64_t>` and initializes it with `vec`, which implies copying `vec`'s state into `vec2`. This is not assignment! If you write instead

```
vec2 = vec;
```

then you have assignment which modifies the state of the object named `vec2` to be equal to that of the object referred to by `vec`. But in order to do that there has to be already a declaration for `vec2` in which the vector object itself has been created. The assignment is not creating a new object.

If you simply use

```
vec = vec;
```

then there is only one object, the one that `vec` refers to. It is non-obvious whether this assignment is allowed at all, but even in the best case all it could do is copy the state of the object that `vec` refers to into the object that `vec` refers to, meaning that at the end the state of `vec` should simply be unchanged and there is no other side effect.

In general you can't rebind a name or a reference in C++ to a new object.

So what you want is

```
std::vector<uint64_t> local_vec = vec;
```

and then you can use `local_vec` as a local copy of `vec`. You can avoid having to specify the type by using `auto` to indicate that you want the variable to have the same type as the right-hand side (minus reference and `const` qualifiers):

```
auto local_vec = vec;
```

Comment: Also: `vec = decltype(vec)(vec);` - create a new "fresh" (temporary) object, copying `vec` into it and then move assigns the result to `vec`.  Perhaps the most expensive `shrink_to_fit` one can come up with :-)

Answer (score 2):

> In rare circumstances, the function needs to locally modify the vector, in which case a copy must be made. Is this the correct way to do that?

If you need a copy `vec = vec` does not help. No matter if `=` skips selfassignement, after that line `vec` still refers to the parameter that the caller passed to the function.

If the function needs a copy rather than a reference, pass the vector by value:

```
int calculate_something(std::vector<uint64_t> vec) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need both, a reference and a copy then pass by reference and make a copy:

```
int calculate_something(std::vector<uint64_t>& vec) {
    auto copy = vec;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally as to what others have said, copy assignment operators in C++ are typically (but not mandatory) implemented as below:

```cpp
SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        // copy the properties of other to this
    }

    return *this;
}
```

So a self-assignment has no effect.

Comment: Not really, this is not a question about being mandatory or not. We do this only in the case the class manages some resources lifetime and if the assignment requires to release the resource before acquiring the new one. In that case, self assignement would be undefined behaviour since it would release the memory and copy the data from the released memory (UB).

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed as a reference, any changes you make to `vec` will be reflected in the variable that was passed into the function.  It's *irrelevant* whether `vec = vec;` makes a copy, because if it does the caller will be using the copy too after your function returns.  You really need to create a second variable to contain your copy.

```
std::vector<uint64_t> vec_copy = vec;
```